# How binding data depending on the value?

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro

I have  ObservableCollection and value that need to find the item in the collection. any ideas? (p.s converter not good idea, because i have many collections)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean. Please provide more details as well what you have tried.

Comment: ` DataContext="{Binding Path=source_id,Converter={StaticResource idToFUser},ConverterParameter={StaticResource Profiles}}"`
this code in converter give me item at ObservableCollection<>Profiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality (applying a filter) belongs into the ViewModel. Here is an easy example for illustration.

You might also want to look at the [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) for a more refined version of the same concept.

[image]

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyClasses}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyFilteredClasses}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MySelectedClass.Name}" Margin="5" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Class1> _myClasses;
        public ObservableCollection<Class1> MyClasses { get { return _myClasses; } set { _myClasses = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyClasses"); } }

        private List<Class1> _myFilteredClasses;
        public List<Class1> MyFilteredClasses { get { return _myFilteredClasses; } set { _myFilteredClasses = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyFilteredClasses"); } }

        private Class1 _mySelectedClass;
        public Class1 MySelectedClass { get { return _mySelectedClass; } set { _mySelectedClass = value; OnPropertyChanged("MySelectedClass"); } }


        public ViewModel()
        {
            MyClasses = new ObservableCollection<Class1>()
            {
                new Class1() { Name = "Connelly" },
                new Class1() { Name = "Donnelly" },
                new Class1() { Name = "Fonnelly" },
                new Class1() { Name = "McGregor" },
                new Class1() { Name = "Griffiths" }
            };

            // filter your ObservableCollection by some criteria, and bind to the result (either another list, or just one item)
            MyFilteredClasses = MyClasses.Where(c => c.Name.EndsWith("onnelly")).ToList();
            MySelectedClass = MyClasses.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.StartsWith("Mc"));
        }
    }

    public class Class1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }
    }
}
```